# Organizing and mapping records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following table of Sales from some Articles

```
id | user_id | article_id | status
1  | 1       | 1          | 0
2  | 1       | 2          | 0
3  | 2       | 2          | 0
4  | 1       | 1          | 1
5  | 2       | 2          | 1
```

Where `status = 0` is **unconfirmed** and `status = 1` is **confirmed**

The logic follows: The user clicks on a button to buy an Article Then, a record is saved on the table with the **unconfirmed** status. After the payment is confirmed, another record is save on the table with the status **confirmed**. Both records are saved on the table to keep a timeline of the whole transaction. The `id` field determines the oldest record from a given transaction.

In my application, I wanted to get a list of **5 Most Sold Articles**, here's how I've done it so far:

```
# In articles_helper.rb

  def get_articles_sold
    # Fetch all Articles that are present in the Sales table
    sales = Article.where(id: Sale.select(:article_id).map(&:article_id))

    sold = []
    sales.each do |s|
      s.status.group_by(&:status).each do |status, sale|
        if status.to_sym == :confirmed
          sold << {article: s, sold: sale.count}
        end
      end
    end

    # Returns the sold array
    sold
  end

# In the Article model there's this Virtual Attribute 'status'
# It returns me the last status from a given transaction

def status
    sales = Sale.where(article_id: self.id).order(id: :desc)

    statuses = []

    sales.group_by(&:user_id).each do |user, sale|
      statuses << sale.first
    end

    statuses
  end

#In my application

@most_sold_articles = get_articles_sold.sort_by{|v| v[:sold]}.reverse
```

It returns me something like:

```
@most_sold_articles = [
   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 4},
   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 2},
   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 1},
]
```

This code actually works and give me what I want, but I think it's a lot of code for a Ruby application. Is there any ellegant or easier way of getting this same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
@articles = Article
  .joins(:sales)
  .select("articles.*, count(sales.article_id) as sold")
  .group('articles.id').order('sold DESC').limit(5)
```

If you want the same format as in your answer

```
@most_sold_articles = @articles.map{|a| {article: a, sold: a.sold}}

#=> [
#=>   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 100},
#=>   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 80},
#=>   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 75},
#=>   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 66},
#=>   {article: #<some_article_entity>, sold: 30}
#=> ]
```

Comment: I'd suggest `.order("sold DESC").limit(5)` so you won't have to reverse the list

Comment: Man... I can't believe ALL my code could be easily reduced by 4 lines!!! I'm feeling such a nOOb right now hahahahahahahhahaha
Thanks for your replies guys, you're the best :)